# How to retrieve data using composite key in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, key, composite

How can I retrieve data using a *Composite key* in hibernate?

1. I have `Roles` tables and a `Permissions` table which is having a one-to-many relationship with the `Roles_Permissions` table. The 
   `Roles_Permissions` table is having a *Composite key* which is formed by *Role id* from the `Roles` tables and *Permission id* from the `Permissions` table
2. I have an embeddable id `Role_PermssionId`.

When I am trying to get data using *Composite key*, I am getting a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive like this

```
CompositePK pk = new CompositePKPK (1, 1);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Roles_Permissions.class,pk);
```

Comment: Thanks Bhusan Uniyal.

Comment: @NethrePaidi if it's helpful then plz accept the answer so it can help others